# Re-define dataframe index with map function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this. I wanted to know how can I apply map function to its index and rename it into a easier format.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=['apple_017', 'orange_054', 'orange_061', 'orange_053'])
df
             d
apple_017    1
orange_054    2
orange_061    3
orange_053    4
```

There are only two labels in the indeces of the dataframe, so it's either apple or orange in this case and this is how I tried:

```
data.index = data.index.map(i = "apple" if "apple" in i else "orange")
```

(Apparently it's not how it works)

Desired output:

```
         d
apple    1
orange    2
orange    3
orange    4
```

Appreciate anyone's help and suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `split()`:

```
df.index=df.index.str.split('_').str[0]
```

OR

via `map()`:

```
df.index=df.index.map(lambda x:'apple' if 'apple' in x else 'orange')
```

output of df:

```
        d
apple   1
orange  2
orange  3
orange  4
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! That's exactly what I want